# LIKE Command in SQL

Tags: python, sql, select, mariadb, where-clause

I tried to write a query with Like command to search for special Name , but i need to get the value from User and i need to read the value but my sql code has problem with "LIKE" section , how can i fix it ?

```
sql = '''SELECT Name FROM newtest WHERE Name LIKE = %s'''
val = (n)
myobj = mycurs.execute(sql , val)
```

what's the problem ?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= %s' at line 1

this is the error

Comment: "my sql code has problem", you got an error, why not tell us what error you got?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/like/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to search for non-exact matches (i.e. the name is anywhere inside the column) you can change the query as:

```
SELECT Name FROM newtest WHERE Name LIKE concat('%', %s, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "=" sign. The LIKE command doesn't use that - see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_like.asp for an example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).